# Failure getting nodes from terms via the rest api

Tags: taxonomy-terms, services, 8

I have added a REST web service in Drupal and all content is tagged with taxonomy. I'm now trying to acquire all related nodes to the terms.

First I'm calling taxonomy_vocabulary/getTree along with the *vid* and I'll get all the terms for a specific vocabulary, that works just fine. The problem comes when I've gotten all the term-id's I need to go through. When I create a request it fails to find the nodes that should be connected to the term. I'll get a 404 response on each request.

This is how I call the **selectNodes**. 
I'm creating a POST request and pass along with the *tid*, the endpoint is called `http://myhostname/api/taxonomy_term/selectNodes`

Have someone else experienced this? Do I need to pass more arguments with the POST call?

EDIT: After a quick look in wireshark it also returns the error string: "String value: No nodes were found with tid 15". Does this mean that there aren't any relation between the terms and the nodes by default?

Answer (score 0):

The taxonomy_term resource is only for returning taxonomy terms. It won't return any nodes.

There are tons of options but here are two that you can do quickly:

1. Install the [Views Datasource](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_datasource) module and create a taxonomy view. Have it output as json.
2. Create a custom resource that handles this. Check out [these](http://pingv.com/blog/an-introduction-drupal-7-restful-services) instructions on creating a custom resource.